# Jquery no displaying alert box when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a simple script that alerts the user what he or she typed in a search box.  Im using Jquery to get the value of the input field when the user clicks the search button.  Nothing is appearing though when I click the search button.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
    alert($('#youtubeSearch').val());
});​
</script>
```

I just need an alert box to appear with the value, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code inside the `.ready` handler. You cannot manipulate `dom` elements before it got ready.

Try this,

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#searchButton').click(function() {
        alert($('#youtubeSearch').val());
     });​
   });
</script>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/e2j9v/)

Answer (score 0):

well.. you need to make sure the element is loaded , before you attach any events to it (click in your case) .. so for that you either have to enclose you code inside document.ready function

```
 <script>
$(function(){
  $('#searchButton').click(function() {
    alert($('#youtubeSearch').val());
  });​
});
</script>
```

or add your script at the end of your HTML just to make user you DOM is ready..